# Android fragment getView() doesnt

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an android application that employs a viewpager to swipe between two fragments.
There are only two pages (each a fragment) one fragment displays images the other textviews.
Once the initial pages are created and displayed the user can change the images displayed by clicking on buttons.
I get the image fragments view using getView(). I have a portrait and landscape versions of the layout.
The code works fine while i dont change the screen orientation. however i get a null pointer when switching between portrait and landscape when trying to access the returned view from Fragment.getView() after switching from portrait to landscape or vice versa.
why is null returned from Fragment.getView() following a change in orientation?

Comment: When are you calling `getView()`?

Comment: i thought thats how i get access to my image views within the fragment so that i can then use "setImageResource(R.drawable.another)"

Comment: I did not ask *why* you were calling `getView()`. I asked *when* you are calling `getView()`.

Comment: sorry, i call getView() on my fragment from within my button onClicklistener. so the sequence of events are a). switch orientation, b). activity onCreate executes c). set button onClicklistener d). screen displays e). i click on the button f). getView on fragment returns null. i get access to the fragment by calling getItem on my pageadapter owned by the viewpager. the pageadapter if a fragmentpageadapter.

Comment: Are you calling `getView()` on the fragment that represents the currently-visible page? Or are you calling it on the other fragment?

Comment: on the current visible page

Comment: I cannot explain why `getView()` would return `null`. `getView()` should work after `onCreateView()` is called, and `onCreateView()` would have to be called in order to display the page. With regards to "i thought thats how i get access to my image views within the fragment", the activity should not be updating the fragment's UI -- the *fragment* should be updating the fragment's UI. The activity should call a method on the fragment, supplying data that the fragment can use to determine what things should be changed. This falls under the "separation of concerns" design guideline.

Comment: thanks for you time commonsware, I know I should be separating my concerns but that didn't work so I was trying to go direct to see if this approach worked. could it be that I am using a fragmentpageadapter where I should try a fragmentstatepageadapter? as I have to change the content of my fragments? all beit iam just switching images inside imageviews

Comment: "could it be that I am using a fragmentpageadapter where I should try a fragmentstatepageadapter? " -- I would not expect that to have an impact, particularly on a two-page `ViewPager`.

Comment: I am using VOLLEY to download the initial images, also my viewpager only takes up the top 50% of my screen layout, the bottom 50% is fixed content and doesn't page. the bottom half of the screen is where my buttons are located. is there something odd about the android fragment magic when switching orientation? is the framework instantiating my fragments in a funny way or recycling the adapter or something?

Comment: "is there something odd about the android fragment magic when switching orientation?" -- fragments get destroyed and recreated when their activities get destroyed and recreated. The new fragments will be called with `onCreateView()` when their `View` is needed for rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your android:targetSdkVersion="12" or less

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

if your  android:targetSdkVersion="13" or more

```
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screensize">
```

Comment: My application has portrait and landscape layouts. I do not want to be catching orientation changes in my code or fixing to portrait only.